# Change Spring boot logging file in main class

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

In main class get logging.file value and append passed argument to it. If same Spring Boot application needs to run more than once, we will pass the some argument to the app and based on argument it will create new logging file. Did anyone come across this use case?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Have you had a look at profile based properties?

Comment: Try editing your question and use some code example so people can get an better overview what yoi are trying to schieben

Comment: @Rentius2407 Yeah, we can have multiple profiles e.g. DEV, UAT or PROD. But that is not what I am asking here. I wanted to append passed argument to value of  logging.file (from .properties or .yml).

Comment: My apologies misunderstood you question. See my edit on the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify `logging.file` when starting the Spring Boot application. No coding necessary:

```
$ java -Dlogging.file=file1.log -jar my-app.jar

$ java -Dlogging.file=file2.log -jar my-app.jar

$ java -Dlogging.file=file3.log -jar my-app.jar
```

If you really want to do it in code, you can do it in `main()` before starting Spring Boot:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("logging.file", "file1.log");
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
}
```

Comment: Sure this is the easiest way. But I have other dependency on arguments, so I wanted to do this in coding. Suppose java -jar my-app.jar 1, then my-app should use something-1.log for logging.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot lets you externalize your configuration.

Document Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

> Inside your app.jar you can have an application.properties file that
>   provides a sensible default property value for "name". When running in a new environment you can launch with a specific command line switch which will override "name". `java -jar app.jar --name="Spring"`

If you want to override the `logging.file` value from the `application.properties`, you can use the following command:

`java -jar app.jar --logging.file=thefileName`

**Edit**:

If you want to append to the logging file in the application.properties you can do the following.

application.properties

```
instance.value=one
logging.file=C:/log/${instance.value}-spring.log
```

The default log file will be `one-spring.log`. 
When running the command `java -jar app.jar --instance.value=two` it will substitute/override the `${instance.value}` with two, `two-spring.log`